# How to random read raw resource file in Android

Tags: android

In my Android project, I have a 2M-bytes raw data file. Since my application is a long-life app, I don't want it to always seize 2M memory. The data file has been formatted, once I need to some data from the data file, I just need to seek to some position and read several bytes.

The Resource class can only return an InputStream on raw file, but InputStream cannot do random read.

Is there a way on Android to random read some bytes from the raw data file? Or I have to read the entire file into memory when I only need a few bytes.

Comment: Would it be possible to split that big file into several smaller files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputStream` can skip bytes with `skip()` can also mark an offset with `mark()`, on `reset()` it can go back to marked position. All that can be used to do random IO.
You can store byte offsets in a separate lookup file as well.

Comment: when skip() on InputStream, I wonder if the underlying implementation is doing seek() or just reading all bytes out that to be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Android is built upon Java so take a look at this tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html